# Why does Pandas round method not round 0.5 up to 1?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I'm posting this with what I think is the answer because I couldn't find a similar question-answer here.

I expected pandas `round` method to round 0.5 up to 1.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]).round()
0    0.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Even more strange: Python's round method has different behaviour in Python 2.7 and 3.6:

Python 2.7:

```
>>> [round(x) for x in [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Python 3.6:

```
>>> [round(x) for x in [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]]
[0, 2, 2, 4, 4]
```

Is this something to do with floating-point representation or my platform (Mac OS X)?

Comment: Thanks @root.  For whatever reason that existing question did not come up when I searched this issue - or even in the list of similar posts when I was writing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in thisc ase it is actually intended behaviour in python, and not a floating point problem. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2)

Comment: Oh, I see.  So it's not floating point representation.  Is there a reason why it is rounded to the nearest even number?  And not say towards zero or "upwards" away from zero (which I always thought it was supposed to be)?

Comment: @Bill For the reasons, read the dupe.

Comment: What is dupe?  I read the Python documentation again and I couldn't find the reason.  But I found an explanation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2120): "I think the reason is to prevent biasing numbers on average upward or downward."

Comment: @Bill, for future reference, "dupe" is short for "duplicate".

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed due to [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) as described in the Python 3 [documentation for `round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) in where it states:

> The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float.

Comment: This misses why 0.5 rounds down to 0, but 1.5 rounds up to 2. Both decimals, having sufficiently small magnitudes and with powers of 2 as denominators, have exact representations in floating point.

Comment: @chepner The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) contradict themselves. They say that the rounding will be toward the nearest even number...but then they say that, well, sometimes it won't be--but that it's not a bug.

Comment: The problem is that 2.675 isn't 2675/1000; it's a number closer to 267/100 and 268/100. Rounding toward the nearest even number *only* applies when the value to be rounded is *exactly* halfway between the two options.